# Release Pipeline Deployment Dashboard

Tags: azure-devops-extensions

I'm looking for a ADO extension that would provide a dashboard contain data that can be use to create metrics.  We have 150+ pipelines that I want to track.

Answer (score 0):

**I found a "[Build Metrics Widget](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AbhinavKhanna.vsts-extensions-dashboard-build-metrics-widget)" which may fit your requirements.**

For more relevant extensions, you can check out this [search results](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=widget&target=AzureDevOps&category=Azure%20Pipelines&sortBy=Relevance).

What's more, in Azure DevOps, there are some built-in widgets for pipelines.

Chart for build history: Shows the build history of a selected build definition.

Deployment status: Shows the depolyment and test status of a branch across the enviornments in your release definitions.

Release pipeline overview: Shows the status of enviornments in a release definition.

Requirements quality: Shows the quality of requirement(s) associated to automated tests.

For detailed information of these widgets, please click [Azure Pipelines widgets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/widget-catalog?view=azure-devops#azure-pipelines-widgets).

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful,  I'm looking a dashboard that will display all my release pipelines and its latest status through each stage (i.e. uat, prod) and also provide a total number of deployments to production.

Comment: @ADO RM Sorry for the late reply. I went through almost all of the widgets for pipelines. None of the widgets can fulfill your requirements. Would you mind a less intuitive approach, such as the release interface or REST API?